# How to show the bot icon in the webchat?

Tags: botframework

I have an image for my bot, but it's not showing up in the webchat.
Is there any way to make it happen like the image in this link (https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/979837/19395693/cbdf6ac2-91f3-11e6-8a48-ba533bf91dca.png) ?

My script for the bot is:

```
<script>

    //Scrip for the webchat window
    (function () {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
        div.outerHTML = "<div id='botDiv' style='height: 38px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 1%; z-index: 1000; background-color: #fff'><div id='botTitleBar' style='height: 38px; width: 350px; position:fixed; cursor: pointer;'></div><iframe width='400px' height='600px' src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/xxx'></iframe></div>";

        document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.target.matches = e.target.matches || e.target.msMatchesSelector;
            if (e.target.matches('#botTitleBar')) {
                var botDiv = document.querySelector('#botDiv');
                botDiv.style.height = botDiv.style.height == '600px' ? '38px' : '600px';
            };
        });
    }());



</script>
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using and describe what you have tried as possible solutions.

Comment: I am using the iframe, I will put the script in the answer. I have changed the name and the logo of the bot in the azure portal, but in the web page only the name has changed.

Comment: Are you using the webchat channel for this?

Comment: Yes, I am using webchat

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you step away from the webchat channel iFrame option and utilize the BotFramework-WebChat tool, instead. The webchat channel is fine for simple deployments, but it isn't overly robust out-of-the-bot.

If you look over sample [04.b.display-user-bot-images-styling](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.b.display-user-bot-images-styling) from the [BotFramework-WebChat repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), you will see precisely how you can effect the bot/user avatars.

In short, you will include the web chat CDN into you html file, assign some basic styling for the web chat div, followed by the script that connects to and generates that actual web chat experience.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Avatar with images and initials</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--
      For demonstration purposes, we are using the development branch of Web Chat at "/master/webchat.js".
      When you are using Web Chat for production, you should use the latest stable release at "/latest/webchat.js",
      or lock down on a specific version with the following format: "/4.1.0/webchat.js".
    -->
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/master/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100% }
      body { margin: 0 }

      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script>
      (async function () {
        // In this demo, we are using Direct Line token from MockBot.
        // To talk to your bot, you should use the token exchanged using your Direct Line secret.
        // You should never put the Direct Line secret in the browser or client app.
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication

        const res = await fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
        const { token } = await res.json();

        const styleOptions = {
          botAvatarImage: 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/v4sdk/media/logo_bot.svg?view=azure-bot-service-4.0',
          botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
          userAvatarImage: 'https://github.com/compulim.png?size=64',
          userAvatarInitials: 'WC'
        };

        window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
          directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
          styleOptions
        }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

        document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
      })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This option does require generating a direct line token. This is accomplished by passing your direct line secret to the direct line /tokens/generate api and receiving a token back. The generated token is tied to the particular session so, as such, provides a certain level of security. Please don't use your secret in this setting.

The below is a node.js example and can be run as an independent app or incorporated into your existing bot as a separate api call made while the html page / web chat is loading. It wouldn't be hard to recreate an equivalent dotnet version.

```js
server.post('/directline/token', (req, res) => {
    // userId must start with `dl_`
    const userId = (req.body && req.body.id) ? req.body.id : `dl_${Date.now() + Math.random().toString(36) }`;
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.directLineSecret}`
        },
        json: {
            User: {
                Id: userId
            }
        }
    };
    request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (!error && response.statusCode < 300) {
            res.send({
                token: body.token
            });
        } else {
            res.status(500).send('Call to retrieve token from DirectLine failed');
        }
    });
});
```

Hope of help!